# Using a textfield as a button

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to use a textfield as a button so when someone taps it, it takes him to a different page.
I've tried disabling the textfield but then I cannot use the onTap property. But if the textfield is not disabled, when I click it, it gets editing focus and this is something I don't want.

Can anyone help what's the easiest way this could be done?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using a TextField widget instead of Text widget?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
TextField(
  readOnly: true,
  onTap: () {
    // Do something
  },
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Flatbutton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FlatButton-class.html) instead. Just put this in your code:

```
FlatButton(
  onPressed: () {
    /*...*/
  },
  child: Text(
    "Clickable text!",
  ),
)
```

Or else use a [GestureDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html):

```
GestureDetector(
  OnTap: () {...},
    child: TextField(
     // Text...
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can wrap it with an InkWell, see below:

```
InkWell(
  onTap: () {

  },
  child: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
    child: Text('Click me'),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following.

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
   // redirect // nav to different screen
  },
  child: TextField(
    enabled: false
    ),
)
```

References

- [TextField](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField-class.html)
- [GestureDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html)